# How to efficiently include results of a MongoDB's cursor in another query?

Tags: python, mongodb

Suppose I have a MongoDB collection and I'm running two queries on it, A and B. Both returning lists of indexes for documents in the collection. I would like to get only those records in the intersection of A's and B's outcome, i.e. the intersection of the sets.

A naive implementation on pymongo would be something like this:

```py
cursor_result_A = db.collection.find(A)
result_A = [x for x in cursor_result_A]
cursor_result_B = db.collection.find({"$and":[{"_id":{"$in":result_A}}, B]})
```

However, this approach makes me first pull all the outcome of the first query from the database to Python and then send it back in the first query. This is very inefficient.

How can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: convert cursor data to sets and do a set intersection?

Comment: @pyjg Quoting myself, "...this approach makes me first pull all the outcome of the first query from the database to Python and then send it back in the first query. This is very inefficient."

Comment: can you not convert results of query A and B to sets in python?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as: `db.collection.find({"$and": [A, B]})`?

Comment: @pyjg If I execute any operation with A's records in Python I will have to move data from the server to the client, and I'm talking about hundreds of millions of records. It is not feasible. I must compute the intersection on server-side.

Comment: @JohnnyHK In this context, for several complex reasons I cannot merge both queries.

Comment: @PedroAlves if you do it in python, how will it be on the client side?

Comment: @PedroAlves Ok; anyway, that's how you would perform the intersection server-side.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Notice that B depends on the list of ids returned by A.

Comment: @pyjg I don't know if I understood your question. The client is querying the server.

Comment: How about using mongo `$lookup`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/?